# Abuse of past perfect, or is it simply fine to do so?

Tags: tiempos-pasados

Ok - first, the definition of past perfect : *"The past perfect is often used to talk about what a person had done before something else happened in the past."*

I am trying to learn basic Spanish, and I noticed when I was in Mexico that people often use past perfect ("había") when they actually are saying something in the simple past tense.

For example, when saying, in simple past tense : "He returned from Mexico" - Can we say :

"Él había vuelto de Mexico" instead of "Regresó de México" ? It must be wrong to use "había" here?

Or, is it "allowed" to use past perfect when adding a "ya" in front, e.g "I told you":

"Ya te lo había dicho". A Mexican told me this several times when actually referring to simple past tense, and I could not understand how it is allowed to use past perfect in this way. Will the use of "ya" convert this to the simple past tense?

So, if we write : "Te lo había dicho" - Then this will be different from "ya" in front? Or can this be used implicitly in a simple past tense as well?

Ok, something similar to this I also witnessed : Let's assume that you are having dinner, and you ask (in the present) if salt is added to the food :

"¿Le añadiste sal? ¡Ya había agregado la sal!" - In my mind, this is wrong, because we are in the present. I am not asking about if the salt had already been added before some point in time in the past.

So my question is if it is correct to use "había" when we are actually referring to a simple past ? If so - *why*? When should we use past perfect in a simple past context, and when should we only use simple past in a simple past context?

Comment: Your use of allow in English is slightly off. That said in THIS: "Le añadiste sal? Ya había agregado la sal!" , your logic is wrong. The first question is simple past so what **precedes that** can be in past perfect.

Comment: Thank you for clearifying the example about the salt, Lambie.

Comment: As a note: it should be taken into account that there are geographical areas where only one of the tenses is used. For example, in the Leonese areas of Spain only the simple past  tense is used.

Answer (score 2):

Both the **Indefinite** preterite (Past Simple) and **The Plusperfect** (Past Perfect) are used in Spanish to express past actions that occur punctually or uniquely in the past. What differentiates them is the reference that is taken to place them in the past. The pluperfect is the past tense.

I will try a comparative explanation that will allow you to differentiate and use them correctly.

Ejemplo

Ayer **hice** una excursión en moto hasta el pueblo de al lado. Ya **había ido** antes con mi tío Roberto, pero esta vez me **atreví** yo solo. Recuerdo que en una ocasión, **recorrimos** más de cien kilómetros por el bosque y **llegamos** a una zona de acampada. Como era día festivo, **habían ido** muchas familias a pasar el día. ¡Nos **divertimos** a lo grande!

The Pasado Pluscuamperfecto tense is the past of Pretérito Indefinido tense, so these tenses often appear together in compound sentences.

Ejemplo:

Rocío **había preparado** durante meses las obras que **presentó** en la galería.

The order of sentences does not necessarily correspond to the order of actions in the past. You have to identify the action that occurred first and express that sentence in Pluscuamperfecto tense.

Ejemplo:

Rocío **presentó** en la galería las obras que **había preparado** durante meses.

---

**Temporary markers or indicators**

Temporary markers allow you to identify the action that takes place before the other. The action in the pluperfect past tense is the one that is accompanied by a temporal marker or indicator to indicate that it is earlier.

*Marcadores o Indicadores Temporales* - *Temporary markers or indicators*

- **Ya**    - **Ya** me había levantado cuando sonó el despertador.
- **Ya**  - **Ya** te lo había dicho
- **El día/mes/año/etc. anterior/pasado**   - Lucía recicló el papel de regalo que había usado **las Navidades pasadas.**
- **Un día/mes/año/etc. antes** - Carlos leyó delante de su clase el poema que había escrito **la noche antes**.

**The logic of prayer**

Temporary markers are not always used. In such cases, logic must be used to identify the action that occurred first and which enables the second to occur.

Ejemplo:

Lucia y sus amigos **se comieron** el pastel que ella **había preparado** por la mañana.

First Lucia prepares the cake in the morning and then she and her friends eat it.

*I hope this has helped you a little more, sorry for the faults.*

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the question. The question, translated to spanish terms, is : "Is it correct to use "pluscuamperfecto" when we are actually referring to a completed action before the present / now ?". So, if I say : "Ya te lo había dicho", and I mean to say "I already told you" (and not "I had already told you") - is that accurate ?

Comment: "Is it correct to use pluscuamperf when we are actually referring to a completed action before the present / now ?" No. "Before the present" is future. Pluscuamperf "when the action of such thing is considered past with respect to another also past". However, the phrases that you say by yourself "El había vuelto de Mexico", "Había hecho", "Ya te lo había dicho" (ya = anteriormente, previously), refer to something that happened in the past, not to the present. I'll try to catch what you're saying, though, and I'll rewrite the question, in case that helps you understand it a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: En español cuando se habla de "Pasado Perfecto" no es posible escribir frases como "había vuelto", "había dicho", "había hecho". That is confusing. Just name the tense.

Comment: @user1511956 The pluscuamperfecto in Spanish is just like pluperfect in English: The action it describes **precedes** another in the simple past.  Fyi, accurate English is: I have already told you. THIS: Le añadiste sal? Ya había agregado la sal!" is: Did you add salt to it? I had already added salt to it. Same thing. The adding of the salt **precedes** the simple past question.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clearifying the example about the salt, Lambie.

Answer (score 2):

No es necesario que la referencia temporal, respecto de la cual está ubicado el verbo en pluscuamperfecto, esté indicada explícitamente en la misma frase o en el texto. [Acá](https://spanishviaskype.com/gramatica/gramatica-b1/el-preterito-pluscuamperfecto-de-indicativo-en-espanol) podés ver un ejemplo del uso que se le puede dar:

> —¿Sabes que el español es el segundo idioma por número de hablantes nativos?
>
> —Sí, algo **había oído**.

¿Antes de qué fue que oyó eso? Claramente, fue antes de que le hiciesen la pregunta. Vos lo que estás haciendo es recortar las frases para analizarlas dentro de la misma y fuera de contexto, pero en todos los casos que mencionaste el uso del pluscuamperfecto es correcto si lo ponés en algún contexto válido:

> Él había vuelto de Mexico. (antes de que sucediera la inundación en Yucatán)
>
> Ya te lo había dicho. (te lo dije antes de que me lo preguntaras)
>
> Te lo había dicho. (te dije que sí/no antes de que tomaras tal decisión, usualmente usado como un reproche por la mala decisión tomada por mi interlocutor)
>
> ¿Le añadiste sal? ¡Ya había agregado la sal! (le agregué antes de que le volvieses a poner otra vez)

Por otra parte, ojo con hablar de "past perfect" en español. Como ya te han respondido, en castellano los nombres de los tiempos verbales son otros y ni siquiera hay una correspondencia biunívoca entre los tiempos verbales del inglés con el castellano. En concreto, el "past perfect" del inglés traducido al castellano es ambiguo en el sentido de que el uso de tal tiempo puede ser correspondido por:

-El **pretérito pluscuamperfecto**, que es por lo que quisiste preguntar y se usa para indicar acciones anteriores a otra acción en el pasado. Vas a ver que en muchos casos es obligatorio el uso de este tiempo y en otros (sobre todo cuando el verbo se especifica con un adverbio de tiempo) puede intercambiarse indistintamente por alguno de los pretéritos simples.

-El **pretérito anterior**, de uso principalmente literario y sirve para indicar acciones que concluyeron inmediatamente antes de que fueran sucedidas por otras en el pasado. En la mayoría de los casos este suele ser reemplazado por el pretérito indefinido sin ningún problema.

Comment: I understand what "el pretérito pluscuamperfecto" is - the point is that in Mexico, they sometimes use the "pluscuamperfecto" when the context actually is "pretérito indefinido" / simple past tense.

Comment: @user1511956 En los ejemplos que diste y a falta de mayor contexto, ambos tiempos verbales son válidos.

Comment: I wrote : "For example, when saying, in simple past tense : "He returned from Mexico" - Can we say : .... " - El contexto se da explícitamente aquí.

Comment: @user1511956 Depende. En este caso es sí o sí pluscuamperfecto porque si no se pierde la referencia de tiempo: "Las inundaciones en Yucatán fueron terribles. Por suerte, él ya había vuelto de México". Y en este ejemplo puede ser cualquiera de los dos: "A: - No saqué entrada para él, porque aún está en México. B: - ¡Pero si ya volvió de México!" , pues *había vuelto* antes de que no lo contaras para ir al cine o bien se puede decir que *volvió* antes de *ahora* ya que no importa el tiempo preciso en el que fue.

Comment: @user1511956 Fueron dos situaciones de las millones que pueden haber, no sé, no te puedo mencionar todas ahora. Lo que más te puedo decir: practicá. Leé libros, noticias, mirá películas y vas a ganar *feeling* sobre el asunto

Comment: Bueno, solo quiero saber por qué se puede usar "el pretérito pluscuamperfecto" cuando el contexto está en "pretérito perfecto simple".

Comment: @user1511956 Ya te lo respondí. Es raro que las situaciones pasadas pertenezcan a un "único conexto". Podés referirlas al *ahora* o podés referirlas a otra acción pasada en función de lo que necesites enfatizar. Por favor, volvé a leer la respuesta y el comentario anterior

Comment: Creo que las situaciones pasadas muchas veces están ligadas a un solo contexto.

Comment: Estás equivocado amigo

Comment: Sería difícil comunicarse sin contexto, amigo

Comment: Pero no es necesario que una única frase esté asociada a un único contexto, puede estar asociada a varios contextos, pudiendo ser válido el uso de ambos tiempos verbales, amigo.

Comment: Por lo general, hay un contexto. Entonces, un tiempo pasado suele ser más preciso que otro. Supongo que por eso tenemos tiempos gramaticales.